# Having trouble with inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

If I have classes like the following:

```
class Person {

}

class SmartPerson {

    public boolean isSmart() {

        return true;

    }

}
```

Can I do something like the following?

```
Person smartPerson = new SmartPerson();
smartPerson.isSmart();
```

I am trying to do something like this, but my problem is that the Person class has no isSmart() method. So how would I go about doing what I am trying to accomplish here?

If you are wondering why I am not just doing

```
SmartPerson smartPerson = new SmartPerson();
```

It is because I am trying to create a game framework with Javafx, and later will extend this framework to create similar games. So I have a Game class in the framework and the game may have a ShootingGame class which will extend the Game class.

So for example, in one of my classes in the framework I may have something like the following:

```
class SomeClassInFramework {
    Game game;
}
```

And then in the game:

```
class SomeClassInGame extends SomeClassInFramework {
    SomeClassInGame() {
        game = new ShootingGame();
    }
}
```

But now when I try to access game.SomeMethodInShootingClass() its not found because the Game class doesn't have it.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Visibility/protection level issues?

Comment: You cannot access a field declared in a child from a parent reference. You either need to cast it or find some other way to achieve what you want. Polymorphism might be the answer here - i.e. have an `abstract` method on `Person`.

Comment: It depends. What do you want to happen if you do `Game g = new Game(); g.SomeMethodInShootingGame();` ?

Comment: No I want to do Game g = new ShootingGame(); and then g.SomeMethodInShootingGame(); Which from the above comments I learned this can't be done unless I do (ShootingGame) g.SomeMethodInShootingGame();

Comment: @Sameer yes, but if you had typed `Game g = new Game(); g.SomeMethodInShootingGame();` instead, what should happen?

Answer (score 0):

method you are trying to call using reference type must be declared or visible to reference type, think this way : how does `Object` know what type of method you are doing to add in class `Foo` ?